# What should be executor thread pool size while using Guava Rate limiter of 5 permits per second?

Tags: java, multithreading, backend, guava

I created an Executor with fixed thread pool size of 50 when I had to process 1500 tasks in total using guava rate limiter(5 permits/second). But I still got 429 for some tasks.
Tasks mean calling 3rd Party API.

How can I make strictly 5 calls per second to third party API?

Comment: Maybe there's some network latency that makes the first call of the next batch taken into account in the current batch? Do you still get 429s with 4 permits per second?

Comment: @sp00m Thanks it works fine with one less than the rate limit. Can you tell what should be ideal size of thread pool executor for such scenario.

Comment: You would need to test it but you likely don't need many threads for this as API requests *normally* take less than a second to complete.

Comment: @dan1st got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problemas, I would use Bucket4J

https://bucket4j.com/

Create

```
            Bandwidth limit = Bandwidth.classic(permitsPerSecond,
                Refill.intervally(permitsPerSecond, Duration.ofSeconds(1L)));
        Bucket bucket = Bucket.builder().
                addLimit(limit).
                build();
```

then

```
bucket.tryConsume()
```

or

```
bucker.asBlocking().consume()
```

Hope it helps